# Set home page in chrome using terminal command

Tags: linux, debian

I need to open a chrome browser (with full screen + localhost:8080) just after login in Debian 8.0 and I am partially able to achieve same with below command-

```
#!/bin/bash
sensible-browser 127.0.0.1:8080  ---- this opens the browser with the URL 

sensible-browser --kiosk 127.0.0.1:8080  ---- this opens the browser in full screen but not with the URL
```

I am thinking of alternate approach that if I can set browser default page using command then above line can work to open browser in full screen but don't know how to do it.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: For this to work, you need to specify default page in browser configuration and That would do. But doing same thing from command-line would require you enter default page parameter every time you invoke the command. Maybe you can write a script.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to the `sensible-browser` command. If you look inside the script (probably at `/usr/bin/sensible-browser`) you may see that this script takes only the first argument.

You can get the expected behavior by running the Chrome executable, usually named `google-chrome`.

Either `google-chrome '127.0.0.1:8000' --kiosk` or `google-chrome --kiosk '127.0.0.1:8000'` will work properly.